# Edit Chrome JS compiler

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, compilation, google-chrome-devtools, dom-events

I want to edit the Chrome JS compiler such that I can emit an event when each expression in console is compiled so as to store the result in an array later on. **How can I do it? I'm not asking for code but direction?**

> > console.log(1)

I want to store the console result in an array without compiling it again.

Comment: do you just want to interrupt each console.log statement and take control on it to do something like want to trigger event. Is it you want?

Comment: Yes, but with every statement I enter in console!